# Generic function for parsing objects

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, generics

What is the best way to parse strings to type taken from argument?

I'm currently parsing XML nodes with the following function, but want to make it generic.

```
    private void ParseSettings(XmlDocument doc)
    {
        IsFormVisible = (bool) ParseNode(doc, "Settings/IsFormVisible", IsFormVisible);
        UpdaterRunInterval = (int) ParseNode(doc, "Settings/UpdaterRunInterval", UpdaterRunInterval);
        UpdaterLastRunTime = (DateTime) ParseNode(doc, "Settings/UpdaterLastRunTime", UpdaterLastRunTime);
    }

    private object ParseNode(XmlDocument doc, string node, object defaultValue)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlNode xmlNode = doc.SelectSingleNode(node);
            if (xmlNode == null)
                return defaultValue;
            string text = xmlNode.InnerText;
            if (defaultValue is int)
                return int.Parse(text);
            if (defaultValue is bool)
                return bool.Parse(text);
            if (defaultValue is string)
                return text;
            if (defaultValue is DateTime)
                return DateTime.Parse(text);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        return defaultValue;
    }
```

Comment: If don't think you could do this generically.  I think you would just be better off using int.TryPares, bool.TryParse etc. then returning appropriate error messages if they do not parse.

Comment: I intentionally return default value in order to recreate broken or missing node. I just don't like that have to check for types and to call Parse for each of them.

Comment: @MiroslavPopov - chk the answer!

Comment: You would still have to check for types, even if you made the method generic.  There is no where clause you could apply to the generic method where you could do something like T.TryParse as there is no base class containing Parse or TryParse that all these types share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private T ParseNode<T>(XmlDocument doc, string node, T defaultValue)
{
    try
    {
        XmlNode xmlNode = doc.SelectSingleNode(node);
        if (xmlNode == null)
            return defaultValue;
        string text = xmlNode.InnerText;
        return SafeConvert(text, defaultValue);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    return defaultValue;
}

public static T SafeConvert<T>(string s, T defaultValue)
{
    if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) )
        return defaultValue;
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(s, typeof(T));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like :

```
private static T ParseNode<T>(XmlDocument doc, string node, object defaultValue)
{
    object ret = defaultValue;
    try
    {

        XmlNode xmlNode = doc.SelectSingleNode(node);
        if (xmlNode == null)
            return default(T);
        string text = xmlNode.InnerText;
        if (defaultValue is int)
            ret = int.Parse(text);
        if (defaultValue is bool)
            ret =  bool.Parse(text);
        if (defaultValue is string)
            ret = text;
        if (defaultValue is DateTime)
            ret = DateTime.Parse(text);

        return (T) ret;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    return (T)ret;
}
```

I cannot assure that, this is the perfect way of doing it, but it works!

```
    IsFormVisible = ParseNode<bool>(doc, "Settings/IsFormVisible", true);
    UpdaterRunInterval = ParseNode<int>(doc, "Settings/UpdaterRunInterval", 1);
    UpdaterLastRunTime = ParseNode<DateTime>(doc, "Settings/UpdaterLastRunTime", 1);
```